# ¿Cómo puedo cargar datos en los campos de un formulario en php?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de cargar los datos de mi base de datos en mysql a mi formulario, pero no sé cómo hacerlo bien; tengo un código mas o menos así se los agradecería mucho.

```
<?php
$rs = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT id, nit, sucursal, ciudad, descuento_comercial, telefono, dias_plazo, direccion, codigo_vendedor, observaciones FROM  pedidos WHERE id = '1' ");
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)) {        
}?>  
echo <option="buscar(<?php echo $row[0]?>)" value="<?php echo $row[0]?>"><?php echo $row[0]." - ".$row[1] ?></option>;
<?php 
?>`
```

Comment: ¿Te funcionaría utilizar PDO en lugar de mysqli para tu conexión a BD? (es recomendable).

Comment: en este caso No

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenté sacar una versión simplificada usando mysqli.
El código lo que hace es sacar todos los valores de la tabla pedidos donde la id sea 1 y guardarlos en un array.s

```
if($resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE id = 1", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
     $formulario = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Para acceder a ellos lo único que tienes que hacer es llamar al array de la siguiente manera $array['nombre_de_tu_columna_en_la_base_de_datos']. Te dejo el ejemplo más abajo:

```
<form class="formulario" method="post">
 <ul>
     <li>
         <label>Dd</label>
         <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $formulario['id']; ?>"/>
     </li>
     <li>
         <label>Nit</label>
         <input type="text" name="nit" value="<?php echo $formulario['nit']; ?>"/>
     </li>
     <li>
         <label>Sucursal</label>
         <input type="text" name="sucursal" value="<?php echo $formulario['sucursal']; ?>"/>
     </li>
     <li>
         <label>Ciudad</label>
         <input type="text" name="ciudad" value="<?php echo $formulario['ciudad']; ?>"/>
     </li>
     <li>
         <label>Descuento comercial</label>
         <input type="text" name="descuento_comercial" value="<?php echo $formulario['descuento_comercial']; ?>"/>
     </li>
     <li>
         <label>Teléfono</label>
         <input type="text" name="telefono" value="<?php echo $formulario['telefono']; ?>"/>
     </li>
     <li>
         <label>Días plazo</label>
         <input type="text" name="dias_plazo" value="<?php echo $formulario['dias_plazo']; ?>"/>
     </li>
     <li>
         <label>Dirección</label>
         <input type="text" name="direccion" value="<?php echo $formulario['direccion']; ?>"/>
     </li>
     <li>
         <label>Códido vendedor</label>
         <input type="text" name="codido_vendedor" value="<?php echo $formulario['codido_vendedor']; ?>"/>
     </li>
     <li>
         <label>Observaciones</label>
         <textarea name="observaciones"><?php echo $formulario['observaciones']; ?></textarea>
     </li>
 </ul>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Luego de que hagas la consulta el array que se forma debes recorrerlo con un foreach y ahi lo puedes colocar el un formulario.

http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php

Si necesitas luego que se muestre en el formulario debe ir dentro de las etiquetas HTML

Y el foreach solo en la etiqueta  lo que se genera dinamicamente son los options, en este sitio te explican al detalle:
https://elporfirio.com/wp/2013/10/como-hacer-un-combo-select-option-dinamico/

La parte especifica que necesitas es esta:

```
<select name="estado" id="estado">
                <option value="">- Seleccione un Estado -</option>
        <?php
        $estados = dameEstado();

        foreach($estados as $indice => $registro){
            echo "<option value=".$registro['idestados'].">".$registro['estado']."</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($rs = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT id, nit, sucursal, ciudad, descuento_comercial, telefono, dias_plazo, direccion, codigo_vendedor, observaciones FROM  pedidos WHERE id = '1' ")){
 echo "<table border=1>"
        . "<tr>"
              . "<th>IDENTIFICACION</th>"
              . "<th>NIT</th>"
              . "<th>SUCURSAL</th>"
              . "<th>CIUDAD</th>"
              . "<th>DESCTO. COMERCIAL</th>"
              . "<th>TELEFONO</th>"
              . "<th>DIAS PLAZO</th>"
              . "<th>DIRECCION</th>"
              . "<th>COD.VENDEDOR</th>"
              . "<th>OBSERVACIONES</th>"               
        . "</tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
      echo "<tr>"
             . "<td>$row[0]</td>"
             . "<td>$row[1]</td>"
             . "<td>$row[2]</td>"
             . "<td>$row[3]</td>"
             . "<td>$row[4]</td>"
             . "<td>$row[5]</td>"
             . "<td>$row[6]</td>"
             . "<td>$row[7]</td>"
             . "<td>$row[8]</td>"
             . "<td>$row[9]</td>"
             . "<td>$row[10]</td>"
         . "</tr>";                    
 }

 echo "</table>";
}else{
 echo "no hay datos en esta consulta";
}

?>
```

Comment: Amigo no es una lista es un formulario donde tengo inputs, pues no estoy utilizando ningún select

Comment: Quiero reflejar los datos en en una tabla

Comment: @ChristianDagnover Si no estás utilizando ningún select, ¿por qué el código que compartes es un option (que iría dentro de un select)?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que es como un ejemplo que tengo; por así decirlo una base

Comment: bueno entonces si lo que necesitas es hacer una tabla  con los resultados de una consulta entonces seria algo parecido a lo que escribi, espera lo modifico

Comment: No es una buena idea usar echo para contenido estático: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180501/which-is-better-to-include-html-inside-php-code-or-outside-it/180504#180504

Comment: @Shaz, interesante articulo gracias por el aporte.

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que no estas pasando el nombre de la columna de la base de datos que estas tratando de traer `<?php echo $row[0]?>` donde tendria que ser `<?php echo $row['nombre_del_campo_que_quieres]?>`